# How to treate some xml structure as a View?

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` with some `Views` in it. Then I want to treat this element as a `View`, so I created a new `class` extending from `LinearLayout`. Now when I dynamically add a new `instance` of this `class` into the layout I see nothing. I believe I have to get the `View` somehow from my `class`, but don't know how. Is it possible to somehow assocciate this new class with an xml?

Update:

```
public class Task extends LinearLayout {

    public Task(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.task_view, this, false);
    }

    public Task(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.task_view, this, false);

    }

    public Task(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.task_view, this, false);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Task newTask = new Task(getActivity());
someLinearLayout.addView((View) newTask); // happens nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different approaches like:

- Inflating it into a `View`
- [Using `<include>` tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

**Inflating:**

```
public class InflatedView extends LinearLayout
{
      public InflatedView(Context c)
      {
            super(c);
            LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_other_layout, this);
      }
      //override other constructors too.
}
```

Now you can use this in your xmls like this:

```
<com.your.package.InflatedView android:layout_height="etc" other:attribute="here" />
```

**Include:**

Very simple, use include tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/your_other_layout"/>
```

Here are RomainGuy's [layout tricks](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/).

Comment: Is it enough to just get it inflated in constructor? Or I need to return it somewhere?

Comment: it is enough, and don't forget to override other 2 constructors.

Comment: Didn't work so far, I'vу put some code in description, please check.

Comment: Pass Context to your `Task()`, you are not passing any thing to the constructor, like: `Task newTask = new Task(YourActivity.this);`

Comment: And you mean simple call for inflater assocciates my xml with derived from LinearLayout class?

Comment: okay, try to take out the last `boolean` argument in `inflate()` method, so it should look like: `inflate(R.layout.task_view, this);`